# Text through figure

Tags: wrapfigure

I started a new document in which I'm working with two columns. I would like to insert figures in a column (using the wrapfig). But,.. text is overlapping my figure. Can someone explain why this happens and how it should be solved?

[image: used Input]
[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far. Not an image of your code, but something we can cut and paste, please.

Comment: Surely a width equal to `\linewidth` doesn't allow the text to wrap around the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wrapfig` package is used to allow text to wrap around figures. This is definitely not where latex shines and, also, obviously not what you want here. Just don't use the `wrapfig` package for this picture and use the usual `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

edit: From David Carlisle's suggestion. The `[htp]` tries to position the figure `h`ere. If this is not possible, then the second option is tried: `t`op position. If that fails as well, latex will put the figure on a seperate `p`age for figures.

Comment: I think the OP wants to use `center` not `figure` here. (or at least `{figure}[htp]`

Comment: Thanks for the respons! You're totally right. The figure environment  does the work!

Comment: @ArdSchakel If this answer satisfies your needs, please accept it so it is not visible in the unanswered questions section.